# OOM and largeHeap request

Tags: android

1. What are the possible side effect of large heap request
2. Is it advisable to use this ?

   ```
   <application
   android:largeHeap="true" >
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

However It's not a good idea to use android:largeHeap="true" here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when task switching or performing other common operations.

Here is the documentation link 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html